# How to 'Upsert' programmatically, using php in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

`Upsert` is a great new thing in PG (we recently updated database to use it) and now we are trying to write upsert adapter in PHP, so that the usage could be simple.

Here is what we should do if we want to upsert:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->_name} AS t ({$insertCols}) VALUES ({$insertVals})
              ON CONFLICT {$onConflict} DO UPDATE
                SET {$updateVals}
                WHERE {$updateWhere}
```

We can shorten it to simplier function, which is more handy in code:

```
ModelTable()->getInstance()->getAdapter->upsert($data, $onConflict, $where);
//e.g.
ModelTable()->getInstance()->getAdapter->upsert(['name=>'Denis', 'age'=>36], '(name)', "name = 'Denis'");
```

In this case usage is more handy, but trouble is - that we have to know the restriction column name (names), or restriction's name itself to put it in $onConflict variable. Variable `'(name)'` in example above.

If one would add another restriction to that table, or rename the old one, the whole php code, that works with that table, should be updated to add new restrictions.

Ideal adapter should look like the regular update adapter:

```
ModelTable()->getInstance()->getAdapter->upsert(['name=>'Denis', 'age'=>36], "name = 'Denis'");
```

So that if the row with `name = Denis` exists, it would be updated, if does not exists, it should be created.

So the question is - how to create adaper in php that would work that way? We know the column name on which row should be updated, so it should be possible to construct `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` sentence. I want to make update on ANY conflict, same as it would be with

```
try {
 ...insert
} catch (Exception $e) {
 ...update
}
```

which we are using now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to implement the `upsert` like catching `\Exception` means «If the insert does not work whatever the reason, I try to update then.» Admit this is a real lack of control of the domain. You may want rows to be updated on conflict with the primary key but rejected when they conflict with a unique field in the same table by example.

The reasons of the conflict belong to the model, these are business rules explicitly implemented as constraints. Only the model layer knows why it would reject an insert and updates a row instead. So it cannot be a generic upsert command you could call on all tables regardless of the domain definition.

This means this is the `ModelTable` instance that knowns why a record would conflict with an existing data the same way it knows the table structure (as I guess from your example).

Comment: You not right when you say that using try/catch is lack of control. You see - when I make an update in `catch` sentence, it can throw an exception if I'm trying to update row with some unique field, that already exists in table.

As far as we use generic `upsert` now, we just put update column key in `ON CONFLICT` clause. E.g. when I make `upsert('table', [name="Denis"], "id = 123")`, the ON CONFLICT sentence will be `ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE`

I'm not quite sure that's its equivalent to try/catch approach, but it works.

Comment: I did not say using try/catch is a lack of control, I said catching all exceptions (class \Exception) without distinction is a lack of control. Exceptions might then be a SQL layer’s exception or a ConnectionException from the layer above. We need to know the kind of exception to know what to do then.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I got it.